# Can't run tasks in Grunt - Task not found| Uncss library

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm

I've decided to optimize my CSS files. Found the library called UNCSS it runs with Grunt.
The problem is that I haven't worked with command line but I've minimal knowledge level.
I'm running Windows 7 X64 and I've installed git for Windows. It integrates with windows command line well. So my workflow is:
1). Install Grunt with Windows installer
2). Navigate with command prompt to my project folder
3). I ran these commands:

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
npm install grunt-uncss --save-dev
```

4). The project folder contains these folders:

```
node_modules->grunt
node_modules->grunt-uncss
```

I've created the Gruntfile.js file inside project's root folder:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    uncss: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'css/style.css': ['index.html']
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-uncss');
//grunt.registerTask('default', 'uncss');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['uncss']);
};
```

5). Running the `grunt` or `grunt uncss` command throws the `Warning: Task "default\uncss" not found. Use --force to continue.`
The only thing which I need is to scan and optimize my projects and make it simple...
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Searched for tutorials but they are the same...

Comment: I have tested your code, It works well if you close the bracket of `uncss`. I have submitted an edit for your post and fixed that bracket in your code.